# Log transformed (+constant) in t-test implication and result

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, data-transformation, logarithm

For context, I am evaluating the level of underpricing, measured as (closing price-offer price)/offering price and underpricing suggests that the result of this calculation is positive.
My H0 for this is that there is no underpricing. Thus y is smaller or equal to 0.
However, my data does not satisfy normality assumption so I transformed the data by log10 (a constant was added prior transformation to include negative returns) and it is confirmed for normality.
I intend to approach the t-test with a "transformed" H0 to:
Log (transformed) is smaller or equal to log(constant added).

The result can thus directly reject or accept the initial H0. Is this correct?

thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Yes and no: your statement of $H_0$ is not sufficiently quantitative to give a definite answer.  A comparison based on raw data with a t-test compares the *difference* of *arithmetic means* while a comparison based on the logarithm compares the *ratio* of *geometric means.*  Although either characterization comports with your intent, *they are different statements.*

Comment: Thanks for your response @whuber . What would you suggest to narrow down my H0, to check whether underpricing is present in the sample. I checked for geometric mean and it seems like the H0 should be adjusted but I'm unsure how, since it is compounding.. I would highly appreciate your help if possible. Or any suggestion of alternative
Note that I cannot use the Wilcoxon test neither because it assumes symmetry, which is not the case of my data